# Connecting to API

Tags: java, python

I plan to build a simple website that takes data from a websites API and puts it into charts that are listed on my website. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Take data from the API listed on localbitcoins.com
   https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/
2. Code a program that parses this data as I see fit.
3. Create a graphical layout that displays the data.
4. Post the graphs on a website that I have created, ideally to update in real-time.

I don't know where to begin.

I am not asking for some one to hold my hand through it all, but more so to give me some pointers on where to start, what resources are there that I can look at, and so on.

My instinct tells that that I need to tackle API and coding part first. Can someone point me to a resource that could take me through this? Should I stick with Java or should I use another language for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little opinion based/broad, and is likely to prompt discussion. Those types of questions are often discouraged. You might be better off trying to ask these questions in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). You also might have more luck at a more discussion oriented site, like [code ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/forums/f-1/java).

Comment: Also, if you're new, it's always good to check out the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Welcome, and I'm sure we can look forward to some more questions in the future coming from this project ;-)

Comment: Also, I just realized you need more reputation for chat, but it might be a good resource for these kinds of questions a little down the road.

Comment: Using LocalBitcoins API test and example app at https://github.com/LocalBitcoins/lbtcex may be a good way to start provided you have the required experience with Python and I would prefer Python for LocalBitcoins since its infastructre appears to have been developed in Python (and they are looking for Python/Django engineers).

Comment: For the backend there are many good choices, and Java is certainly a good choice, as is Python. For the front end you'll almost certainly want to know something about Javascript (there are other choices like Flex/Action Script but javascript pretty much owns this space). There are many good javascript libraries to help you with the front end, such as jQuery and a charting library called Flot, among others. Google something like "the best javascript charting tools"  and you'll find several good articles on this topic. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the belated response. Thank you Jim!